# Swift Generic Unbound Wildcard Type

Tags: swift, generics

Is there any way to write the following in Swift. I can't seem to find a good alternative for the unbound wildcard type "?". Maybe this pattern could be handled differently in Swift.

```
class MyDefinition {}

class DefinitionBuilder<B: DefinitionBuilder<?, T>, T> {}

class ObjectDefinitionBuilder<B: ObjectDefinitionBuilder<?, T>, T>: DefinitionBuilder<B, T> {}

class MyDefinitionBuilder: ObjectDefinitionBuilder<MyDefinitionBuilder, MyDefinition> {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "this pattern" really is. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, you can define `DefinitionBuilder` as `protocol` which uses `associatedtype` and `Self` like this:

```
class MyDefinition {
    var a: Int = 0
}

protocol DefinitionBuilder {
    associatedtype T

    func withA(a: Int) -> Self

    func build() -> T
}

protocol ObjectDefinitionBuilder: DefinitionBuilder {

}

class MyDefinitionBuilder: ObjectDefinitionBuilder {

    private var _def = MyDefinition()

    func withA(a: Int) -> Self {
        _def.a = a
        return self
    }

    func build() -> MyDefinition {
        return _def
    }
}

let definition = MyDefinitionBuilder().withA(5).build()
```

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use

```
class DefinitionBuilder<B: DefinitionBuilder<AnyClass, T>, T> {}
```